# Highcharts stacked bar chart with different categories

Tags: javascript, ruby, highcharts

My ruby back-end produces a JSON hash with categories with array of subcategories in it (each subcategory has total value):

```
{"IT, Internet, Telecom"=>[["Testing", 3], ["Banking Software", 1], ["ERP", 2], ["IT Security", 2], ["Consulting, Outsourcing", 1], ["Project Management", 1]], "Accounting, Management Accounting, Corporate Finance"=>[["Offshore", 1], ["ACCA", 1]], "Administrative Personnel"=>[["Workflow Management", 1]]}
```

This hash is in data variable.
I need this to convert as a stacked-bar chart (highcharts) with total number of category (For "IT" it is 10) and also stacked subcategories within this category (3,1,2,2,1,1). The problem is that I want to have category columns with subcategory pieces of unrelated data of each category. Here is what I already tried:

```
$(function () {
  function drawChart(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, point) {
        point.y = point.data;
      });
      var chart = Highcharts.chart('seekers_by_category', {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Seekers category'
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> seekers'
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y} seekers',
                style: {
                  color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
          },
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Seekers',
            data: data
          }
        ]
      })
    });
  }
  var mainUrl = $('#seekers_by_category').data('url');
  drawChart(mainUrl);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have converted JSON to this format:

```
[{:name=>"Testing", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 3]]}, {:name=>"Banking Software", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 1]]}, {:name=>"ERP", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 2]]}, {:name=>"IT Security", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 2]]}, {:name=>"Consulting, Outsourcing", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 1]]}, {:name=>"Offshore", :data=>[["Accounting, Management Accounting, Corporate Finance", 1]]}, {:name=>"Workflow Management", :data=>[["Administrative Personnel", 1]]}, {:name=>"ACCA", :data=>[["Accounting, Management Accounting, Corporate Finance", 1]]}, {:name=>"Mutual Funds", :data=>[["Banks, Investments, Finance", 1]]}, {:name=>"Project Management", :data=>[["IT, Internet, Telecom", 1]]}, {:name=>"Assistant", :data=>[["Marketing, Advertising, PR", 1]]}]
```

with:

```
g = {}
h.each do |k,n|
  a, b = k
  g[b] = [] unless g.key?(b)
  g[b] << [a, n]
end

g.map{ |k, v| { name: k, data: v } }
```

and changed series to just:

```
series: data
```